# Elliptical precession of magnetic moments due to external magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I have a magnet lying in the XY plane which happens to have an in plane Anistropy along +X. If I apply a field along +Z, the magnet, if initialized not along +Z, is expected to precess about +Z. However, the amplitude of precession along X and Y will not be the same because of the anisotropy. Let's also assume, the field is applied only in a localized region in space (by an antenna).

**In this situation, how can I calculate the distance up to which the magnetization dynamics would reach?**

(In ideal case without any anisotropy, I would estimate it to be $v_g\frac{1}{\alpha\omega}$
, where $v_g$ is the group velocity and $\alpha$ is the damping constant of the magnet)